# How do I sort and rsort files based on two parts of the filename in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, sorting, glob

I'm currently echoing all the names of the files in a given directory with php.
The files have a naming convention:
Year person was born _ last name first name
eg.
1980_doejohn.php
    1980_elfsarah.php
    1981_fitzjack.php
    1983_guptasiva.php

I need to rsort them first by year, and sort within each year so the output should be:
1983_guptasiva.php
1981_fitzjack.php
1980_doejohn.php
1980_elfsarah.php

My current (non sorting) code is:

```
<?php
$filename = glob("about/*.php");
rsort($filename);
    foreach ($filename as $filenamein) {
        echo ($filenamein) . "<br>";
    }
?>
```

How should I modify it to make it sort the way I want it to? Please provide the entire code suggestion including the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to write your own comparison function for this and use [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). This works:

```
$filename = glob("about/*.php");
usort($filename, 'filename_cmp');

foreach($filename as $filenamein)
    echo ($filenamein) . '<br />';

function filename_cmp($a, $b){
    $diff = (int)substr($b, 0, 4) - (int)substr($a, 0, 4);
    if($diff !== 0)
        return $diff;
    return strcmp(substr($a,5), substr($b,5));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much; that almost works perfect but I actually need the years to sort from most recent to oldest like in my example. Your code sorts like:1980_doejohn.php, 1980_elfsarah.php, 1981_fitzjack.php, 1983_guptasiva.php instead of: 1983_guptasiva.php, 1981_fitzjack.php, 1980_doejohn.php, 1980_elfsarah.php

Comment: @amesguich Hmm... it sorts correctly on my computer. Try switching the `$a` and `$b` in `(int)substr($b, 0, 4)`